# How to mitigate this strange pattern shown in Phong lighting?

Tags: opengl, graphics, lighting

I am creating an entire lighting scene in OpenGL. The entire scene consist of only one point light. I noticed some strange z-fighting like pattern. This flickers when I move the camera.

[image: Artifact 1]
[image: Artifact 2]

Can anyone tell me what is the potential cause of the problem? How should I mitigate this problem? Thank you.

===

EDIT: The problem is solved. It was primarily caused by normal transform computation error and my ill made model might have been aggravated this speckle flickering effect.

Comment: This is not the only problem, your entire lighting seems to be incorrect...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I realized that. I am debugging the problem right now.

Comment: A low density of subdivisions shouldn't cause a speckled artifact like that. This might indicate another problem that was only masked by subdividing the wall. Are you using shadow mapping?

Comment: @DMGregory No. My shader only consists of standard phong lighting (with specular map and diffuse map). I think the problem might be influenced by my errors in normal transform computation. I accidentally invert the order of multiplication of two matrix (namely, world and view matrix). This problem is resolved now.